# Googleスプレッドシートから特定のシートだけCSVに書き込む

Tags: python, csv, google-spreadsheet

やりたいこと：
Googleスプレッドシートから特定のシートだけを取得してCSVに書き込みたい。

現在下記のコードだと全てのシートを取得し、CSVで書き込むことはできます。

```
import csv
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials.json', scope)

docid = "123"

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(docid)
for i, worksheet in enumerate(spreadsheet.worksheets()):
    filename = docid + '-worksheet' + str(i) + '.csv'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(worksheet.get_all_values())
```

[gspreadから情報を取得しました。][1]

こちらのコードで試してみましたが"sheet2"を取得しようとすると
「ssdownload.py」のファイルだけ生成され、開くと実行したコードが表示されます。

```
import csv
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials.json', scope)

docid = "123"

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(docid)

def worksheets(self,title):##new
    sht = client.open('Sheet2')##new
    worksheet = sht.get_worksheet(0)##new
    for i, worksheet in enumerate(spreadsheet.worksheets()):
        filename = docid + '-worksheet' + str(i) + '.csv'
        with open(filename, 'w', newline="",encoding='utf_8_sig') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(worksheet.get_all_values())
```

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。

Comment: 英語で恐縮ですが、こちらの情報はお役に立ちますか？ https://stackoverflow.com/q/65460817

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。不明なところがございましたらコメントください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

次のサイトがよくまとまっています。
[gspreadライブラリの使い方まとめ！Pythonでスプレッドシートを操作する | たぬハック](https://tanuhack.com/)

特定のシートのみをcsvへエクスポートしたいという処理だと、下記のような感じになります。
workbookをスプレッドシートキーで指定しています。
自分の環境に合わせて、お使いください。
SPREAD_SHEET_KEY=''
CSV_FILENAME = "./test.csv"
SHEET_NAME='シート1'

```
import gspread
import json
import csv
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials 

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

SPREAD_SHEET_KEY=''
CSV_FILENAME = "./test.csv"
SHEET_NAME='シート1'

workbook = gc.open_by_key(SPREAD_SHEET_KEY)
worksheet = workbook.worksheet(SHEET_NAME)
with open(CSV_FILENAME, 'w', newline='') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerows(worksheet.get_all_values())
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。上記の方法で試したら問題なくできました。